# How to draw these t-statistics in R

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

When determining the necessary sample size for a `t test` of a difference of mean of two populations a good rule of thumb is typically $$ n = 16 {\sigma^2 \over \delta^2}$$ where $\delta$ is the threshold above which you want to detect a difference in the population means. However, if you want to reverse engineer this to say "Given a sample size $n$, how  big of a difference can I detect between the two means", then the calculation for $\delta$ is given [here](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-run-an-ab-test.html) as $$ \delta = (t_{\alpha/2} + t_{\beta})\sigma \sqrt{2/n}$$

I'm wondering what distribution to draw the above t-statistics from. Here $\alpha$ is typically $0.05$ for a $95\%$ confidence interval, and $1 - \beta$ is the power of the test. In `R`, would it be 
`t_alpha_2 = abs(qt(.025, df = df))` for $\alpha = 0.05$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $t_{\alpha/2}$ statistic correspond to the top $\alpha/2$ quantile of the standard student-t distribution and not the bottom as you suggest in the question. This explain why you get a negative value (and therefore i assume take the absolute value of the result).

Here is the r code for the statistics:

```
t_alpha_2 <- qt(1 - alpha/2, df = df)
t_beta <- qt(1 - beta, df = df)
```

However, as you are dealing with a symmetric distribution you will get the same result as the one you suggested. But this is only because it is symmetric. Had you done the same for the exponential or $\chi^2$ distribution for another test you would not get the same result.